# Return type does not include 'undefined' but switch is exhaustive

Tags: typescript

I do not understand the error in this minimum example

```js
interface List {
    "A": false,
    "B": false,
}

// Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.ts(2366)
// Why?
function foo<T extends keyof List>(letter: T): List[T] {
    switch (letter) {
        case "A":
            return false
        case "B":
            return false
    }
}
```

What value could `letter` take so that my function returns undefined?

Comment: `T` *extends* `"A" | "B"`. You don't handle any extension, maybe remove the generic type and use `letter: keyof List` instead: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAM5mQbwFDKHICCAXMgEYD2VANhHCANwFEBC51dDzeAvnjwwAriARhgVEMhg0AFPTCQo5ANYQAnlRhpMYAJSca9RrlaEMAd2BgEAC2QKIS6PrNEPyBHAwoARMR+pOaeHlDOwlDSYFDCECyhhN6+yH5sQSGJyOFgkdLwtL4JRAICQA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should take care of your use case:

```js
function foo(letter: keyof List): List[typeof letter] {
  switch (letter) {
    case 'A':
      return false
    case 'B':
      return false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there no way to keep `keyof List` as generic type `T`?

Comment: Your implementation is specific to `List`, even if you could make it generic, I dont see any benefit/difference